# "Save as" multiple files from node view with rules

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-rules

I have a view of nodes. This node type has a file field with remote mp3 files (I have only url of mp3 in a **link field**). And this view has a VBO field. I want that my users to be able of select some nodes with VBO and "save as" the mp3 of these nodes in their computers.

I think that is possible with rules, but I don't know how. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this will help but I assume you will need to package all the files selected prior to starting the download (with rules, I assume).

But first did you check this question? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31209/download-attached-files-in-a-zip

Comment: I think this module is not suitable for me, because mp3 files are remote, I only have the url.

Comment: If no other solution comes through I would look at building a small module that takes your node ids as parameters, downloads the files, archives them and returns the archive for download. This is going to put a load on your server so you may also think of storing these files/archives to speed up popular downloads.